# How to keep track of messages exchanged between a server and clients?

Tags: algorithm, client, chat, server

My app sends notification to the pc when a new text message is received on the phone. I am doing that over bluetooth if it matters.

(This is relevant to PC side)

What I am struggling with is keeping track of messages for each contact. I am thinking of having a linked list that grows as new contacts come in. Each node will represent a new contact.

There will be another list that grows vertically and this will be the messages for that contact.

Here is a diagram to make it clear:

```
 =======================
| contact 1 | contact 2 ...
 =======================
    ||           ||         
 =========    =========
 | msg 0 |    | msg 0 |
 =========    =========
    ||           ||         
 =========    =========
 | msg 1 |    | msg 1 |
 =========    =========
    .            .
    .            .
    .            .
```

This will handle the messages received but how do I keep track of the responses sent? Do I tag the messages as TAG_MSG_SENT, TAG_MSG_RECEIVED etc?

I have not written code for this part as I want to do the design first.

Why does it matter?

well when the user clicks on a contact from a list I want to be able display the session like this in a new window:

```
==============================
|          contact 1         |
==============================
|Received 0                  |
|                      Sent 0|
|                      Sent 1|
|Received 1                  |
==============================
```

I am using C/C++ on windows.

Comment: Do you need to database or doing this in main memory is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be to use of existing file systems to store message as follows :-

> 1. Maintain a received file and sent file for each contact in specific folder.
> 2. Name them contact-rec-file and contact-sent-file.
> 3. Every time you receive or send message.
> 4. Append the message to corresponding sent or receive file
> 5. first write the size of message in bytes to the end of file
> 6. then write the content of the message.
> 7. Whenever you need to display messages open the file
> 8. read the size of file then read the contents of message using the size.

**Note:** Using main memory to store message is pretty inefficient as a lot of memory is used if there are more messages sent.

**Optimization :-** Use another file to store the number of messages and their seek position in send or receive files so that you can read that file at loading time and then directly seek the file to correct position if you to read only particular message.

Comment: thanks, I never thought of writing to file. It takes alot of pointer stuff out. can you please explain #5, when you say write size of message to end of file.

Comment: you can use a single file for storing the messages but for that you need an separator to separate the messages. so store the messages as (size1,message1),(size2,message2).... Using this format you can first read size of the message and read the message using size. This technique prevents use of any separator to separate the files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to keep track of, If you just want the statistics of the sent and received messages, then two counters for each contact will do.  If you just want the messages sent and received by the client, not caring about how they are interleaved, then 2 lists for each client will do.  If you also need to know the order of how they are interleaved, then as you suggested, a single list with an additional flag indicating if it was a sent or received message will work.  There are other possibilities definitely, these are just to get you started.

Ok, if order matters, then here are 2 more ways that I can think of off the top of my head:

1) in the linked list, instead of having a flag indicating the status, have 3 next pointers, one for next message, one for next sent message, one for next received message.  The next message pointer will have the same value as one of the others, but that's just so you can know how they are interleaved.  So now you can easily get a list of sent messages, received messages, both, or some other weird walk.

2)  Have only 1 linked list/array/table, each entry will include the contact info and the SENT/RECEIVED flag.  This is not good if there's lots of other info about the contact that you wish to keep since now they need to be replicated.  But for simplicity, only 1 list instead of list of lists.  To remedy this problem, you could create a separate list with just the contact info, and put a reference in the messages linked list to this contact info list.  You could also create a contacts_next_message pointer in the list of messages, this way you can walk using that and get all of that contacts messages.

And so on, there's lots of ways you can do this.

Comment: Yes order matters :) Just like when you click on a contact on your phone and see the text messages exchanged.